# API call for user count in Chrome Web Store?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have an extension in the Chrome Web Store and I like knowing roughly how many people are using it via the "N users" and ratings [on its page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ddldimidiliclngjipajmjjiakhbcohn).

However, I don't really like loading the whole "product" page just to see a couple of numbers and thought I'd try to make a little widget that would display it instead.  However, I can't find any API documentation for the Chrome Web Store.

I would a call like `/webstore/api/v1/appid.json` to exist, but the closest things I've found in searching [only concern the Licensing API](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/index.html).

Is there an official Chrome Web Store API for user metrics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is no such API.

You can use [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tut_analytics.html) inside an extension to track users manually.

If you don't need anything fancy, just a number of installs and users, there is [My Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igejgfmbjjjjplnnlgnbejpkpdajkblm) extension, it will track those numbers for you.

Comment: Thanks @serg! I never knew that extension existed and it's saving me a lot of time. Also, Google Analytics is a godsend for tracking visitors to your page and I've found that annotating my graphs with each release helps make more sense of it.

Comment: Thanks @serg -- I didn't know about that extension.  It looks really useful.  Out of curiosity, I poked around in its popup inspector and found that the author is doing HTML scraping on the "product page" in the Web Store rather than hitting an API endpoint.  That explains things.  :)

Comment: can confirm. I also wanted to find an api and ended up on the same route as "My extensions"

Answer (score 6):

Copy and paste the snippet below wherever you want in the body of a html document saved with a ".php" extension.

```
<?php

//URL of your extension
$url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ddldimidiliclngjipajmjjiakhbcohn";

//Get the nb of users
$file_string = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('#>([0-9,]*) users</#i', $file_string, $users);
$nbusers = str_replace(",", "",$users[1]);

echo $nbusers; //Display the number of users

?>
```

Comment: A ScrAPI, eh?  :)  I was hoping to avoid HTML scraping, but it's what I'm doing (using node.js, however).

Comment: I believe this broke as of the last Chrome Web Store front-end refresh.

Comment: I have submitted an edit to this post that fixes it for the latest version of the webstore.

Comment: Quick, "ugly" and most of all - working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this client-side only (at least on your end) by using a cross-domain tool. This snippet will grab the number of users displayed on the Chrome webstore page for an extension (up-to-date as of April 28, 2018):

```
var chromeExtensionWebstoreURL = 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/background-image-for-goog/ehohalpjnnlcmckljdflafjjahdgjpmh';

$.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(chromeExtensionWebstoreURL) + '&callback=?', function(response){
    var numUsers = ((""+response.contents.match(/<span class="e-f-ih" title="([\d]*?) users">([\d]*?) users<\/span>/)).split(",")[2]);
    console.log(numUsers);
});
```

In the future, Google may change the class name of the user count span, in which case you just need to update the regex appropriately.