# How to get chrome extension's meta information (e.g. version, name) from Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I want to get chrome extension's version, name from chrome web store.

For example, I can see the app name "Do Not Merge WIP for GitHub" and the app version "1.0.6" in [application's detail html page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/do-not-merge-wip-for-gith/nimelepbpejjlbmoobocpfnjhihnpked).

How to get these meta data?

I can find only publish API.

[Using the Chrome Web Store Publish API - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api)

Html page uses ajax/detail API, but I feel this API is too internal.

E.g. [ajax/detail API](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ajax/detail?hl=ja&gl=JP&pv=20141016&mce=rlb%2Csvp%2Catf%2Chcn%2Cgtc%2Cc3d%2Cncr%2Cctm%2Cac%2Chot%2Cfcf&id=nimelepbpejjlbmoobocpfnjhihnpked&container=CHROME&_reqid=169881&rt=j)

Related:

- [API call for user count in Chrome Web Store? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005026/api-call-for-user-count-in-chrome-web-store)
- [Chrome webstore search API to lookup by name to get app id - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156738/chrome-webstore-search-api-to-lookup-by-name-to-get-app-id)

Comment: Late, but did you want to get just your own extension's data or another extension's data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that with public APIs.

The Publish API doesn't work with this metadata, [this](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items#resource) is what it can extract.

So usually people just scrape the Web Store page.

Comment: Thanks! This is bad news :cry:

Answer (score 3):

I built npm modules for gathering metadata by scraping.

- [chrome-web-store-item-property](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-web-store-item-property)
- [chrome-web-store-item-property-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-web-store-item-property-cli)

Example:

```
$ chrome-web-store-item-property-cli nimelepbpejjlbmoobocpfnjhihnpked | jq .
{
  "name": "Do Not Merge WIP for GitHub",
  "url": "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/do-not-merge-wip-for-gith/nimelepbpejjlbmoobocpfnjhihnpked",
  "image": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/chrome/webstore/images/thumb.png",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "price": "$0",
  "priceCurrency": "USD",
  "interactionCount": {
    "UserDownloads": 421
  },
  "operatingSystems": "Chrome",
  "ratingValue": 4.5,
  "ratingCount": 2,
  "id": "nimelepbpejjlbmoobocpfnjhihnpked"
}
```